# Conky system temperature monitoring, execigraph empty

Tags: 16.04, temperature, conky, sensors

G'Day, Mat here.

Just wondering if anyone can shed light on why the Conky execigraph would be empty.

The screenshot shows execi, execibar, and execigauge all working, but not execigraph.

[Screenshot of conky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e86YB.png)

The screenshot code for Conky:

> `TEXT
>   ${execi 1 sensors -u | grep -A 0 'temp2_input' | cut -c 15-19} C
>   ${execibar 1 sensors -u | grep -A 0 'temp2_input' | cut -c 15-19}
>   ${execigauge 1 sensors -u | grep -A 0 'temp2_input' | cut -c 15-19}
>   ${execigraph 1 sensors -u | grep -A 0 'temp2_input' | cut -c 15-19}`

My other graphs work well, and I've tried

> `${execigraph 50,500 1 sensors -u | grep -A 0 'temp2_input' | cut -c 15-19}`

but adding the size dimension only draws an empty box.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 7):

I got it working surrounding the command to execute with " ", here below my usage as example:

```
${execgraph "sensors | grep 'Core 0' | awk '{print $3}' | cut -b2,3"}
```

It worked fine with both execgraph and execigraph; additionally, remember to set your default graph size, for example: default_graph_size 175 25 .

Comment: Please edit your answer and format your code as such ( using the `{ }`button )

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the quotes around the command, and most other exec commands actually seem to work without quotes but not execgraph.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set something for `default_graph_height` and `default_graph_width`? From the man page

> Specify a default height/width for graphs. This is particularly useful for  execgraph and execigraph as they do not take size arguments

<sub>(It's also possible that the "new" conky 1.10.x is just buggy, it doesn't use the same tested reliable config format but "*introduces a new Lua-based conkyrc configuration format*", and apparently has trouble with graphs & drops a lot of functionality like *${pre_exec}*)</sub>